# How to remove Blend for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, blend

After uninstalling VS2012, Blend for Visual Studio 2012 is still there (both in Start Menu and in Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 11\Blend), even after I ran the installer with /uninstall /force (which removes all optional components). How can I remove it from my system? Is there an installer for Blend?

Comment: You try to uninstall from Programme / Fonctionnality ? Or try to remove with CCleaner?

Comment: Tried removing it with "Uninstall or change a program" and running the /uninstall argument of the Visual Studio setup exe.

Comment: The problem with visual studio, when we try to uninstall, all the file is not remove and sometimes it's impossible after this to uninstall all the visual studio world in your computer. The best way is to format your pc but it's really tired to do this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I might have found a way:

1. In `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{57F20F04-014D-453F-B6A3-AE9485C4DFAB}v5.0.30709.0\packages\Blend_Core`, right-click Blend_Core.msi and click Uninstall.
2. In `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{532DBCC8-9468-435C-AEF6-30B7F50735A2}v5.0.30709.0\packages\Blend_LP`, right-click Blend_LP.msi and click Uninstall.

Comment: I don't know whether this is perfect, but as it's the only approach we currently have, +1 for you!

Answer (score 0):

I was more concerned with removing Blend from the start menu than removing it from my harddrive (because I kept opening blend accidentally when I want VS).

To do this, type blend in the start menu.  Right-click on the Blend option that comes up, and click click 'Open file location' (For me, this opened C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2013).  Delete the link to blend from that location and it will stop appearing in the start menu.

Comment: is this for all users or just the current?